# React-Router: Handling Deeply Nested Routes with Class Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Trying to figure out how to navigate through deeply nested class component routes, and I'm a bit lost as to how to do it correctly.

So here's the general architecture of the components:

```
--Component L
  |_Component L1
  |_Component L2

--Component S (accessible after authentication)
  |_Component S1
    |_Component S1.1
      |_Component S1.1.1
      |_Component S1.1.2
  |_Component S2
    |_Component S2.1 
    |_Component S2.2
    |_Component S2.3
      |_Component S2.3.1
  |_Component S3
    |_Component S3.1
```

And technically the nested components may go much deeper than what's shown. The general idea is that components `L` and `S` are parental containers (or anchors) for smaller components; components such as `S1`, `S2`, and `S3` are components of different categories, and there are more components under each category. At all time the top-most component `S` is visible and provides buttons/tabs to navigate to one of the components `S1`, `S2`, and `S3`, which should be drawn inside a `canvas div` in component `S`. Only the content in this `canvas div` should be updated with each route change.

Currently, to navigate between `L` and `S`, I have the following `Switch` set up:

```
<Switch>
    <Route to='/L' component={L} />
    <AuthRoute to='/S' component={S} />
</Switch>
```

and component `S` looks roughly like this:

```
export default class S extends Component {
    <Menu>
        <Button>to S1</Button>
        <Button>to S2</Button>
        <Button>to S3</Button>
    </ Menu>
    <div>
        <Content >
            Child components should be drawn in here.
        <Content />
    </ div>
}
```

The documentation demonstrates an example using `useRouteMatch()`, but that is only available inside functional components.
How can this be done with class components?

EDIT: Forgot to mention but each child component offers a way to go back to the parent directly above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Switch>
<Route to='/L' component={L} />
<AuthRoute to='/S' component={S} />
```

is your first layer routing.

you just need to do the same for L and S components.

inside your L components.

```
 <Switch>
    <Route to='/L/L1' component={L1} />
    <Route to='/L/L2' component={L2} />
  </Switch>
```

inside your S components.

```
 <Switch>
    <Route to='/S/S1' component={S1} />
    <Route to='/S/S2' component={S2} />
    <Route to='/S/S3' component={S3} />
  </Switch>
```

do the same for each layer when the hierarchy goes down.

Comment: Ok, but how should I navigate to, for example, ```/S/S1``` from a button click within ```S```? It seems that if I do ```this.props.history.push('/S/S1')``` from within an ```onClickHandler``` in ```S```, react-router will try to match this route against routes in the parent ```<Switch>``` (where only ```/L``` and ```/S``` are listed). This will end up redirecting to a 404 page because it cannot find the route specified.

Comment: Oh I think I know why: I had ```exact``` for my route to component ```S```. Thank you!